# Swapping a step down converter

Tags: converter, step-down, graphics

[image: Back of a graphics card PCB, the step down converter in Q501 has a leg missing (TSOT-23-8)]

I have a faulty graphics card i am trying to repair, i noticed on the back near the 12v connector that a step down converter in Q501 had a leg missing (right side, second from the bottom) and i am not sure what the cause was (possible corrosion?).

I have a few questions regarding repairing this:

1. What would be the easiest way to swap out the step down converter with a replacement.
2. What is the space in Q505 for as it looks like a step down converter in the TSOT-23-8 package would fit.

The step down converter in question: https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Monolithic-Power-Systems-MPS/MP1475DJ-LF-P?qs=Iq7RKQRjpgoaxnjiXuhBAA%3D%3D

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thankyou.

Comment: Nicely done photo - I wish thay were all that good. That's not "missing a leg" - it has been blown apart - presumably by electrical failure. There is a reasonable prospect that there is other damage. [Datasheet here](https://nz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MP1475_r1.01-1384080.pdf) . Look for damage on lines connecting to pins 2 (input) and 3 (output  ) BUT could be anywhere.  |  Cap equivalent to C2 in datasheet MAY be short.

Answer (score 1):

Nicely done photo - I wish tehy were all that good.

That's not "missing a leg" - it has been blown apart - presumably by electrical failure.

There is a reasonable prospect that there is other damage. [Datasheet here](https://nz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MP1475_r1.01-1384080.pdf).
Look for damage on lines connecting to pins 2 (input) and 3 (output) BUT could be anywhere.

The capacitor equivalent to C2 in datasheet MAY be short.